# Adding attribute using JOIN to Collection

Tags: adminhtml, collection, grid, magento-1, product-collection

I have the following code snippet in my _prepareCollection function.  In this collection, I am missing an attribute that I need to have in order to display to a grid(style number).  I am able to access the attribute using the entity_id from the collection, but I have no idea how to go about joining this attribute to my collection.

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {

 $collection = $this->getOrder()->getProducts();
    foreach ($collection as $item){
        $styleNumber = Mage::getModel('Catalog/Product')->load($item->entity_id)->manufacturersstylenumber;
        //Join this style number to $collection     
     }

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

**Edit:** Output of `$collection->getSelect()->toString();`

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `catalog/product`.*, `Purchase/CatalogProductDecimal`.`value` AS `sale_price`, `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`value` AS `small_image` FROM `purchase_order_product` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `catalog/product` ON entity_id=pop_product_id
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `Purchase/CatalogProductDecimal` ON `catalog/product`.entity_id=`Purchase/CatalogProductDecimal`.entity_id and `Purchase/CatalogProductDecimal`.store_id = 0 and `Purchase/CatalogProductDecimal`.attribute_id = 64
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` ON `catalog/product`.entity_id=`catalog_product_entity_varchar`.entity_id and `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.store_id = 0 and `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.attribute_id = 75 WHERE (pop_order_num = '3')
```

**Edit:** I suppose my question is how would I create a join using entity_id to my catalog/product and adding the styleNumber attribute for my addColumn later.

Comment: Is this a custom module? What does `$this->getOrder()->getProducts()` do?

Comment: yes, it's a an extension module that was downloadable. that line is simply just a way to load up the collection with certain parameters. Either way, it's similar to calling     $collection = mage::getModel('purchase/order');

Comment: And does `$this->getOrder()->getProducts()` return an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` ?

Comment: getOrder() function is `$this -> order = mage::getModel('Ppurchase/Order')->load($value); return $this`

Comment: I'm more curious how `getProducts` looks like. Add the code to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure where it is to be honest. The system is huge.  I can output `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()` and show you the query if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

without knowing how the `getProducts` method looks like I can take a shot and advice you to try this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() 
{

    $collection = $this->getOrder()->getProducts();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturersstylenumber');

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

This only works if `getProducts` returns an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`

Comment: This is one of the first thing I tried to do, and sadly it does not work.  I'm fairly certain that getProducts does not return that collection, but `manufacturersstylenumber` is definitely within  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`. I just need to figure out how to join it

Comment: I don't know if this will work because the collection is not able to be modified after it has already loaded. I believe getProducts() calls an explicit load.

Comment: Yep. If load is called then it's forever.

Comment: I don't know about getProducts(), but getOrder() calls an explicit load.

Comment: Do you guys know how I can just do a simple join for this $collection with the 'Catalog/Product' table? Knowing the entity_id